# Prove $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ if $\alpha < \beta$

Tags: ordinals

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinal numbers and $\beta$ is limit ordinal.

I assume the proof is relatively simple because it's been omitted in my textbook.
Could someone also provide an intuitive way to think about ordinal arithmetic?

For example (got this from Wikipedia), I can imagine $\omega\times\omega=\omega^2$ to be $1<2<3<...1<2<3<...$ repeating for every natural number. So a countably infinite number of sequences of countably infinite number of numbers. Then it makes sense that $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2$ because prepending one more sequence of natural numbers doesn't change anything. But how can I generalize this for any ordinal?

Also, this way of thinking doesn't really explain why $\omega^2+\omega$ suddenly isn't equal to $\omega^2$ since the same reasoning could be applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is false. For example, $\omega+(\omega+\omega)\neq\omega+\omega$, despite the fact that $\omega<\omega+\omega$.

You can show that $$\alpha+\beta=\beta\iff\alpha\cdot\omega\leq\beta.$$
The proof of the above equality is not difficult:

1. If $\alpha+\beta=\beta$, then for every $n<\omega$, $\alpha\cdot n+\beta=\beta$. Therefore $\beta\geq\alpha\cdot n$, for all $n<\omega$, so $\beta\geq\sup\{\alpha\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}=\alpha\cdot\omega$.
2. In the other direction, if $\alpha\cdot\omega\leq\beta$, then there is some $\gamma$ such that $\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\beta$. Now we have that: $$\alpha+\beta=\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\alpha\cdot(1+\omega)+\gamma=\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\beta.$$

---

An intuitive way of thinking about ordinal addition is that $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$ if we can partition $\gamma$ into an initial segment of $\alpha$ and an end segment of $\beta$ (and nothing else, since it's a partition).

Now, given two well-orders one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other, so the difference must be pronounced in the end segments. And this is why $\omega^2+\omega\neq\omega^2$.

Comment: Does the fact that $\beta$ is a limit ordinal change anything? I've edited that part of the question in a bit later so you might have not seen it.

Comment: I gave an example, $\alpha=\omega$ and $\beta=\omega+\omega$, then $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You're right. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure, it's good practice. I need to write solution manuals for my students, and the equivalence I wrote here was one of the exercises in last week's assignment.

Comment: May I please ask for some explaination on why If $α+β=β$, then for every $n<ω,α⋅n+β=β$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9: Induction, of course.

Comment: The proof is elegant, easy and yet I couldn't find the statement in the several textbook I consulted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SK19: Sounds odd. But I'm glad to hear it helped.